# Bash - Formatting values

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've written a simple account script in bash and I couldn't find out the standard way of how displaying a floating point value. Is this the best solution using awk? Balance is also printing out 0.00, did I forget to include something?

```
#!/bin/bash

function printBalance()
{
    echo | awk 'BEGIN { printf "\nCurrent balance: %.2f\n", balance }'
    sleep 1
}

function makeWithdraw()
{
    echo -en "\nWithdraw an amount: "
    read deposit

    if [ "$withdraw" -gt "$balance" ]; then
      echo -en "\nInsufficient funds"
      sleep 1
    else
      balance=$(( balance - withdraw ))
    fi
}

balance=$((RANDOM%100+1))

# code continues...
```

Comment: `awk`'s `printf` works the same as `c`'s, so it's fine the way you do it.

Comment: Phew, I'm still getting used to Bash. Balance is a random number I'ved seeded below, any idea as to why it's printing out zero? @fedorqui

Comment: What's the purpose of the `echo |` in your `printBalance` function?

Comment: I totally didn't catch that, thanks @KeithThompson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I see what was missing: `awk` needs to have the variable `balance` given:

If you have `$myvar` you have to:

```
awk -v awk_internal_var=${myvar} '{printf "%s", awk_internal_var}'
```

In your case:

```
echo | awk -v balance=${balance} 'BEGIN { printf "\nCurrent balance: %.2f\n", balance }'
```

So that's why it was printing `0.00`: because it did not get the value.

Comment: I see, I really appreciate the explanation. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Just use bash's built-in `printf` command:

```
$ printf '%.2f\n' 123.456
123.46
```

I'd also suggest using `printf` rather than `echo` for anything complicated. There are multiple versions of `echo` in various shells and as separate programs. The same is true of `printf`, but its behavior is much more consistent.

For example, rather than

```
echo -en "\nWithdraw an amount: "
```

you can use:

```
printf '\nWithdraw an amount: '
```

or, if there's a possibility the string could contain `%` characters:

```
printf '\n%s: ' 'Withdraw an amount'
```

Comment: Making the changes now! Is there any difference between using single quotes vs. double quotes? I know in php double quotes are considered "magic".

Answer (score 0):

[Greg says](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022) `awk` should do it

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.3f\n", 10 / 3}'
3.333
```